# How to fetch from nodejs-api-starter into react-starter-kit

Tags: node.js, rest, graphql, react-apollo, react-starter-kit

I am trying out React-Starter-Kit for the first time and loving all the cutting edge features baked in (apollo/graphql-client in particular). A crucial part of any app for me is the database, and for that my understanding is the same author provides nodejs-api-starter which sets up a REST interface for accessing Postgres at localhost:5000 and has a graphql webui at localhost:5000/graphl.

That is about as far as I have been able to understand of the setup so far. I have changed the frontend code a little bit so a new Component "Counter" is loaded on the home page. I need to be able to make  a new counter, fetch the latest counter, and increment decrement the counter. Write now the component just outputs the 'value' retrieved from the server at 5000.

I do not think I am accessing the 5000 server correctly, do I put the port in this [url line](https://github.com/Falieson/react-starter-kit-crud-counter-demo/commit/d9b06160e35c1ebbc9618f6c26e084c1503cd6dc#diff-c17e7804d1abf173db1a6a5ea0d999d9R15) somehow?

You can pull the repo down from : https://github.com/Falieson/react-starter-kit-crud-counter-demo

This is my first time setting up a nodejs api server, I am used to using MeteorJS which has pub/sub to MongoDB baked in. I am looking forward to the separation the RSK strategy (which seems more industry standard?) provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just done setting up the full site with Database from React-Stater-Kit, I'm also a newbie so I understand your frustration.

About this question, you don't need the NodeJS-API-Starter, it has enhanced function ( such as Redis cache ) and it's not suited for newbies. You should look deeper into the RSK, it already has the DB. If you ran the boilerplate and played around, change is you'll see file database.sqlite in your folder, it's the database. Here are the things you should learn:

1. Use [SequelizeJS](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/) to connect the NodeJS server with database. Your database can be MySQL/MariaDB, PostgreSQL or SQLite. The connection is easy and there's [tool](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) to auto-generate Models from your database
2. How to create GraphQL's Types and Queries. If your queries need to search through the database, import Sequelize's models and use its functions.
3. Test your API via GraphQLi

Note: if you want to use MongoDB or other NoSQL, try [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) instead of Sequelize.